# Comparar dos horas Android

Tags: java, android

**Quisiera saber como puedo comparar dos horas de manera correcta en Android.
He estado leyendo, y pues econtré una posible solución.

Método:

```
private boolean horas(){
    //para la hora actual
    Calendar actual = Calendar.getInstance();
    actual.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    actual.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //para la hora final
    Calendar fin = Calendar.getInstance();
    fin.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
    fin.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 39);

    if(actual.equals(fin) || actual.after(fin)){
        carga.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }else{
        carga.setEnabled(true);
        return false;
    }
}
```

`onCreate`:

```
    if(horas() == true){
        Toast.makeText(ListaPreciosActivity.this, "Lo sentimos, las cargas y modificaciones de precio solo se pueden realizar hasta las 20:00 hs.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        carga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cargarPrecio();
            }
        });
    }
```

La idea es que luego de la hora indicada, se inhabilite el botón pero no me ha funcionado. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el fragmento de código

```java
Calendar actual = Calendar.getInstance();
    actual.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    actual.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

No es necesario poner los get ya que getInstance obtiene todos los datos diréctamente.
El problema principal está en:

```java
fin.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
```

Ya que el campo correcto a utilizar es HOUR_OF_DAY el caul es donde se almacena la hora del día.

Luego lo que sucede también es que evalúas la condición antes del onClickListener del botón. No se como tengas concebido el funcionamiento del algoritmo. Pero te dejo más abajo una sugerencia:

Método:

```java
private boolean horas(){
        //para la hora actual
        Calendar actual = Calendar.getInstance();

        //para la hora final
        Calendar fin = Calendar.getInstance();
        fin.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        fin.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

        return actual.equals(fin) || actual.after(fin);
    }
```

Modifiqué la fecha fin siendo consecuente con el mensaje Toast que dejas en el onCreate. Quité la habilitación/deshabilitación del botón para que este no pierda su propiedad clicable luego de quedar deshabilitado. Simplifiqué el return.

OnCreate:

```java
carga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (horas()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lo sentimos, las cargas y modificaciones de precio solo se pueden realizar hasta las 20:00 hs.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else cargarPrecio();
            }
        });
```

Como ves la condición de horas() la evalúo dentro del listener del botón para que ocurra cada vez que este sea clicado. El if lo simplifiqué ya que horas()==true es una redundancia.
Espero que te pueda servir. Un saludo